# Span text does not change

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text that is inside a span. I've tried using the .innerHTML but it didn't work. Now I tried this:

```js
var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name")
user_name.innerHTML = "New content"
```

```html
<div class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><span id="user_name" class="d-none d-lg-inline mr-2 text-gray-600 small">Anastasios Papapanagiotou</span></a>
<div class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in 
role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Profile</a><a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Settings</a>                                        
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a></div>
</div>
</a>
```

And instead of saying Text inside the span I would like to say New Content, but change it using javascript

Comment: You have a typo: It's `document` and not `docuemnt`

Comment: oops, I changed it, but still nothing :(

Comment: Works fine in the snippet

Comment: Still, on my website, it does not change. Would you like some more code, maybe that will help some more.

Comment: Where is your JS code in relation to the document?  Is it in the head tag?  The body tag?  We do need enough code that we can fully understand the issue.  If the snippet doesn't reproduce the issue, it makes it harder to analyze the issue.

Comment: It is inside, the body tag.

Comment: Do you want the text to change on the click of the words?

Comment: I added some more code. @King11 I would like to change the Text just when I refresh the page.

Comment: Maybe your function execute before span element loaded.

Comment: If that's the case, what should I change?

Comment: put your `script` tag in the bottom, before the `</body>`

Comment: Tried that, still nothing.

Comment: @AnastasisPap. Please *show us* your code.  We still cannot reproduce your issue.  If the code in the snippet cannot reproduce the issue, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `textContent` instead of `innerHtml`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uat13fog/

And change your `getElementById("user_name")` to `getElementById('user_name')`

Use single quotes instead of double quotes

jsfiddle using your updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/5zw18uv4/

Comment: If this answer didn't work for you, try removing all the classes from that element and see what it results in. You may have a style that is making it hidden.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why this wouldn't work. I cant seem to figure out why its not working for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
 function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("user_name").innerHTML = "New content";
}
```

```html
<a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
  <span id="user_name" onclick="myFunction()"> Text </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thing is that I do not want the text to change when I click, I would like to change every time I refresh the webpage. Thanks though :)

Comment: So change action to start the function from onclick to onload...

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and seams to work, I don't see any problem.

https://codepen.io/bratorimatori/pen/WNNZBwg?editors=1111

```
var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name")
user_name.innerHTML = "Changed text"
console.log(user_name);
```